# Clone EC2 instance with all things installed

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I received a amazon email saying that i have to terminate my instance because of attacks but i worked really hard to install and setup everything on the instance.

I've tried to create a image and on the AMI create a new instance and launch another instance like this. but it not worked.

So how can i create another instance with the stuff that i installed on the current instance?

By the way have some way to copy everything on the instance?

Someone could please spare some hint?

thank's

Comment: The instance launched from the AMI should work exactly as the original instance unless the data was not persistent. What is not working?

Comment: well, i created but the things not show up anymore

Comment: Trying to make an image from a server you *know* has been compromised so that you can start up a new machine **makes no sense** -- your new instance has exactly the same security vulnerability as the old one, and probably has the same malicious code on it that was running on the other one.  You do not try to fix or salvage the software installed on a compromised machine.  You start over.

Answer (score 0):

If the instance security is compromised you should really start from scratch.

But if you need to access data from the older instance you can create a Volume snapshot and then attach it to the new instance.

I know it's annoying to setup everything again, so I keep a shell script to configure everything remotely and I run it each time I create a new instance. If you were trying to setup a LAMP server, you could write an install.sh script with something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

SERVER_IP= ...
SERVER_ADDR=ec2-user@$SERVER_IP
SERVER_PEM=/../../key.pem

sudo ssh -t -t $SERVER_ADDR -i $SERVER_PEM <<-EOF1
     sudo yum update -y
     sudo yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd
EOF1
```